# Postgres aggregate between JSON columns

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate

I have a Postgres DB with tables for templates and responses, each template defines how many rows and items it has, the response places the items in rows. I want to be able to query a merged response with the "average" placement across all responses for any template.

**template_post**

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"items":[{"id":0},{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}],"rows":[{"id":"0","title":"First row"},{"id":"1","title":"Second row"},{"id":"3","title":"Third row"},{"id":"4","title":"Fourth row"}]} |
| 2 | ... |

**response_post**

| id | template_id [FK] | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | {"filled_rows":[{"row_id":4,"item_ids":[0,1,3]}]} |
| 2 | 1 | {"filled_rows":[{"row_id":2,"item_ids":[2]}]} |
| 3 | 1 | {"filled_rows":[{"row_id":0,"item_ids":[1]},{"row_id":2,"item_ids":[2]},{"row_id":4,"item_ids":[3]}]} |

In this case, the query should return the following merged response:

```
{
  "filled_rows": [
    {
      "row_id": 0,
      "item_ids": [1]
    },
    {
      "row_id": 2,
      "item_ids": [2]
    },
    {
      "row_id": 4,
      "item_ids": [0,3]
    }
  ]
}
```

In cases of ambiguity, when an item appears the same number of times in more than one row, it should be placed in the first one of those rows.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL you are running? Is it 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few levels of aggregation here.

- Firstly, in a correlated subquery, break out the `filled_rows` and `item_ids` into separate rows.
- Aggregate by `item_id` and take the min `row_id`.
- Aggregate by `row_id` and take a JSON array of `item_ids`.
- Aggregate the whole thing up to get all rows in one JSON

```sql
SELECT
  tp.id,
  r.result
FROM template_post tp
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      jsonb_build_object(
        'filled_rows', jsonb_agg(byRow.*)
      ) AS result
    FROM (
        SELECT
          byItem.row_id,
          jsonb_agg(byItem.item_id) AS item_ids
        FROM (
            SELECT
              MIN((r.value ->> 'row_id') ::int) AS row_id,
              i.value::int AS item_id
            FROM response_post rp
            CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(rp.data -> 'filled_rows') r
            CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements_text(r.value -> 'item_ids') i
            WHERE rp.template_id = tp.id
            GROUP BY
              i.value::int
        ) byItem
        GROUP BY
          byItem.row_id
    ) byRow
) r;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/w-a8rhM6)